# How to Declare and Initialize a New Array Inside ngFor?

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

I am trying to add some dummy records in an ngFor loop without having to declare the array in the component file. Is this possible? Something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let repeat of new Array(8)">
   <ngx-skeleton-loader></ngx-skeleton-loader>
</div>
```

It works when I do it this way:

```
<div *ngFor="let repeat of mockRecords">
  <ngx-skeleton-loader></ngx-skeleton-loader>
</div>
```

And in the component file:

```
mockRecords: Array<any> = new Array(8);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation#syntax) you cannot use new in the template.

You could define the dummy array with its items directly:

```
   <div *ngFor="let repeat of ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']">
      <ngx-skeleton-loader></ngx-skeleton-loader>
   </div>
```

Comment: That's what I thought. I wasn't seeing anything that would suggest otherwise both online, and trying different things on my end. Thanks for the input!